# Using .children and .find in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I have a set of controls on my page that I am attempting to iterate through and determine if they have values.  Some of these controls are <select> items and in this instance I need to loop through the options associated with the <select> control and find the ones that are selected.  I have tried .children() as well as .find("option:selected") and neither of them work (both throw an "undefined" error in javascript).  What am I doing wrong?

```
function getJsonValue(control, json) { 
    if(control.dataset["fieldname"] !== "undefined"){
        if(control.tagName == "SELECT") {
            var selected = "{";
            var idName = control.dataset["idname"];
            control.children.each( function() {
                if(this.selected) {
                    selected += idName + ": " + this.val() + ",";
                }
            });
            selected += "}";
            if(selected != '') {
                json += control.dataset["fieldname"] + ": ";
                json += selected + ",";
            }
        } else {
            if(control.val() != '') {
                json += control.dataset["fieldname"] + ": ";
                json += control.val() + ",";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The error is appearing on line 5 of the above code (control.children.each).  I've tried:

```
control.children.each( function() {
control.childre().each( function() {
control.find("option:selected").each( function() {
```

None of these options work.  For reference, the "control" variable is passed from another function that is found by doing the following:

```
$("#search-header").find("select").each( function() {
    json = getJsonValue(this, json);
});
```

Comment: `control` is not a jQuery object, that's why jQuery methods don't work on it. Use `$(control)` instead.

Comment: bad idea trying to create json manually, it is very error prone. What is expected results for this code? There are easier ways to go about doing this by creating real objects and using `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I don't think you should need to do any looping with `each()`. You could use `$(control).find(':selected')` or if you bind the `idName` to each option value then you could just use `$(control).val()`.

Comment: Also will fail if `<select>` is `multiple` as your code will be creating same property more than once and you will also have an extra trailing comma... which is part of the error prone problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further extend on my comment, I can see that you are passing the object `this`, which is assigned to the variable `control` in your function. However, jQuery cannot directly operate on this object unless it is converted into a jQuery object, and this can be done simply by wrapping it with the jQuery alias, `$(control)` (hint, just like how people use `$(this)` in jQuery, it's the same thing).

Therefore, if you revise your code this way, it should work:

```
function getJsonValue(control, json) { 
    if(control.dataset["fieldname"] !== "undefined"){
        if(control.tagName == "SELECT") {
            var selected = "{";
            var idName = control.dataset["idname"];
            $(control).children.each( function() {
                if(this.selected) {
                    selected += idName + ": " + this.val() + ",";
                }
            });
            selected += "}";
            if(selected != '') {
                json += control.dataset["fieldname"] + ": ";
                json += selected + ",";
            }
        } else {
            if(control.val() != '') {
                json += control.dataset["fieldname"] + ": ";
                json += $(control).val() + ",";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

p/s: On a side note, if you ever want to access the original DOM node from a jQuery object, just use `$(control)[0]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(control).find("option:selected").each( function() {
```

or

```
$(control).children.each( function() {
```

You are passing (this) to you function from the caller. It doesn't have jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Open close bracket on first children

```
control.children().each( function() {
control.childre().each( function() {
control.find("option:selected").each( function() {
```